# Repopulate select2 data when using form_validation() CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I am trying to repopulate my form using `select2` and codeigniter's `form_validation()`, but I can't get it working. My select2 plugin is using json type data. Here is my select2 `HTML` code:

```
<select name="secondary_icdx" id="multiple-secondary-icdx" class="form-control" data-url-source="<?php echo site_url('frontoffice/diagnose/code'); ?>"></select>
```

And here is my select2 `javascript` code:

```
var sourceDiagnose  = $('#multiple-secondary-icdx').data('url-source');
$("#multiple-secondary-icdx").select2({
    closeOnSelect: false,
    placeholder: 'Select secondary diagnose if any...',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    language: {
        inputTooShort: function () {
            return "Type min. 3 characters...";
        },
        noResults: function() {
            return "Nothing found!"
        },
        searching: function() {
            return "Searching…"
        }
    },
    ajax: {
        url: function (params, data) {
            return sourceDiagnose + '/' + params.term;
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        processResults: function (response) {
            return {
                results: response,
                pagination: {
                    more: (response.page * 30) < response.total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

I tried using `if` statement when `$_POST['secondary_icdx']` is set, inside select element like so:

```
<?php if ( isset($_POST['secondary_icdx']) ):
    foreach ( $_POST['secondary_icdx'] AS $sec ):
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $sec; ?>"><?php echo $sec; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; endif; ?>
```

...but no luck! Is there any way of using `set_select()` or something else when the form is validating? I'm totally confused. Any help here would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

**NOTE :** icdx code has more than 22k data!

Answer (score 0):

you only need to run foreach if value is already saved and rest will be done by select 2 itself. remember update the select 2 file, and set the select box to multiple.
i am using the cdn:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

and here is my code:

```html
<select class="form-control select2" id="health_type" name="health_type[]" multiple="multiple">
<option value="all">--Select Health Concern Type--</option>
 <?php foreach ($health_type as $cat) :?> 
<option value="<?=$cat['id'];?>" <?php if(!empty($health_arr) && in_array($cat['id'], $health_arr) ) echo 'selected'; ?> ><?=$cat['name'];?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

my select 2 intialisation:

```js
$('.select2').select2({
    placeholder:"Select multiple variants"
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2').select2();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your code is different than mine, I'm using select2 ajax data source. I'm not looping data directly into select2 element. As mention in PS, icdx code has more than 22k data!